# Opening an Excel workbook macro from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

First of all, I have searched and read similar threads and I have tried the solutions that were proposed and solved the other people's problem (mostly using single quotes around the workbook name) but it hasn't worked in my case.

What I want to do is very simple: I want to call an Excel workbook from Access. The workbook is already open (using VBA) so this is not an issue of the workbook being closed. Here is how I attempt to run the macro:

```
Application.Run "'" & xlWb.Path & "\" & xlWb.Name & "'" & "!mainParcourirTrouverItem"
```

Results in:

`'I:\47491\...\Trouver items global.xlsm'!mainParcourirTrouverItem`

I have tried a few variations like not using the complete path (only file name), not using single quotes, adding parentheses at the end of the sub's name...

Also, I have double-checked that the spelling of the sub name is actually correct. I really don't see it :|

Oh and just for the sake of giving context, here is the complete sub surrounding this code:

```
Private Sub Commande10_Click()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    With xlApp
        .Visible = False
        Set xlWb = .Workbooks.Open(FichierImportExcel, ReadOnly:=True)
    End With

    Application.Run "'" & xlWb.Path & "\" & xlWb.Name & "'" & "!mainParcourirTrouverItem"

'    Call importer_transitsrubriques_Click
End Sub
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I use `"'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!SetMenu"` in my own code. Have you tried using just `Application.Run "'" & xlWb.Name & "'" & "!mainParcourirTrouverItem"`, since the file is already open? (Simply remove the parth from the call.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xlApp.Run`  not `Application.Run`

`Application` will refer to Access, not Excel.

Comment: Hey thanks. I knew it had to be something stupid. I will accept the answer when it becomes available. Do you also have an idea why I now get an error message telling me that it cannot activate it (which tells me that it did indeed find it but cannot run it for some reason) ?

Comment: Try testing your Application.Run line from the Excel immediate window - that might tell you osmething useful.  Or post the exact error message here.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. I solved this by using the module name in front of the sub name.